# Passing a 2D slice to a Golang function argument

Tags: go

I'm trying to scan a matrix from the stdin and simply print it using following code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func print2D(arr [][]int) {
    for i:=0; i< len(arr); i++{
        for j := 0; j< len(arr[0]); j++{
            fmt.Printf("%d ", arr[i][j])
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}

func main() {
    var arr [6][6]int
    for i:= 0 ; i < 6 ;i++ {
        for j := 0; j< 6; j++{
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &arr[i][j])
        }
    }
    print2D(arr[:])
}
```

It throws the following error

> ./main.go:23: cannot use arr[:] (type [][6]int) as type [][]int in
>   argument to print2D

Is there a way to pass a 2D slice without defining sizes in the function arguments?

Comment: Do you need to use arrays for some reason? There’s no problem if you start with slices.

Comment: @JimB could you give an example how to use 2d slices in this case? what if the matrix dimensions are 3x4?

Comment: What is the "matrix definition"? If the type is `[3][4]int`, then that's the type you need to use. If the type is `[][]int`, then they can have any dimensions.

Comment: Besides, when you pass an array as the argument to the function/method, you copy the whole array, i.e., inside the function/method you modify its copy. If you using slice, you can modify it on the fly without an extra copy. The rule of thumb is whenever it's possible path slice as the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write the data directly to the slice and pass it later to the function. Remember array and slices are different types. Moreover, the type `[3]int` is also different from `[4]int` (size matters).

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func print2D(arr [][]int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(arr[0]); j++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", arr[i][j])
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}

func main() {
    var arr [][]int
    for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
        tmp := make([]int, 6)
        for j := 0; j < 6; j++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &tmp[j])
        }
        arr = append(arr, tmp)
    }
    print2D(arr)
}
```